# What is the license for RPi.GPIO?

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, licensing

I can't find a copy of the RPi.GPIO python package license. [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) suggests there is one but can't point me to it. Does anyone know where to find a copy of the license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The license is surprisingly difficult to find. I downloaded the latest release from its [sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberry-gpio-python). It looks like an MIT (included below).

## License included in Jessie Distro - Feb 09th, 2017

> Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Ben Croston
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
>   this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
>   the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
>   use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies
>   of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
>   copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
>   IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
>   OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
>   SOFTWARE.

Comment: That's not a custom license - it's just the old [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) (widely regarded as a permissive "do as you please, just include the copyright" license, [TLDR legal](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mit-license) has a summary)

Comment: @DaveJones Ah. I didn't recognize it without the label.